# tooltip using d3-tip not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to implement a tooltip in svg using Angular, d3 v4, d3-tip.

here's the JS logic

```
var data = [{
    train: 1
}, {
    train: 2
}, {
    train: 3
}, {
    train: 4
}]
const tip = d3Tip()
let svg =d3.select('svg')
tip
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(d => {
    return (
      `<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style="color:red"> test</span>"` 
    )
  })

svg.call(tip)
let selectedElms = d3.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data, function(d) {
    console.log(this.id)
    return (d && d.train) || this['id'];
  })

selectedElms
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

  }
```

The problem is that nothing is shown on screen but I have noticed that when I hover the elements the `tip` function is triggered ( chrome debugger )

```
return (
      `<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style="color:red"> test</span>"` 
)
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-tip-angular-example-ayhr6b?file=app/d3-chart/d3-chart.component.ts) for code working but unfortunately I can't reproduce the error.

I want to mention that is my real example that this code bellow is inside an observable subscription

```
let selectedElms = d3.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data, function(d) {
    console.log(this.id)
    return (d && d.train) || this['id'];
  })

selectedElms
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

  }
```

Comment: #infodev: Tooltip not showing as per dynamic data, is this your issue here?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is tooltip not showing as per dynamic data then replace the below code, the tooltip will start showing -

```
    tip.offset([-10, 0]).html(d => {
      return (
        "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" +
         d.train + "</span>"
       );
     });
```

[image: Scrrenshot with tooltip(e.g - Frequency: 1]

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Pls, check above screenshot where Frequency: 1 is showing when placed the mouse pointer over the circle area.

Comment: Yes as I said the example works , but not my real one, I can't reproduce the error

Comment: Then you need to share the real one, so I can debug the code for you :)

Comment: @Sayan Would you be so kind to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468246/stackedbar-chart-with-missing-tooltip-in-angular-and-d3-js) question please? We have been stuck in this for a few days now...