# StackedBar Chart with missing ToolTip in Angular and D3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have adapted [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_hover.html) example to work with the latest `Angular` and `D3`.

It works fine (after a little hack) but I do not get the tooltips when hovering, etc...

[image]

```
<h3>Stacked Bar Chart with Tooltips</h3>

<figure id="stacked-bar-tooltip"></figure>
```

If you search for this ID, you will see that it is the single point of drawing:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stacked-bar-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './stacked-bar-tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stacked-bar-tooltip.component.css']
})
export class StackedBarTooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [
    {"group": "Insulin", "Low": "6", "Normal": "2.75", "High": "5.25"},
    {"group": "Vit B12", "Low": "1", "Normal": "3", "High": "1"},
    {"group": "Vit D3", "Low": "1", "Normal": "3", "High": "1"},
    {"group": "Zinc", "Low": "1", "Normal": "3", "High": "1"}
  ];

  svg: any;

  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    this.drawBars(this.data);
  }

  createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3.select("figure#stacked-bar-tooltip")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 2))
    .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 2))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  drawBars(data): void {
    
    // List of subgroups; i.e. the header of the csv data:
    // Prepare the array with the keys for stacking.
    const dataColumns = Object.keys(data[0]);
    const subgroups = dataColumns.slice(1)

    // List of groups; i.e. value of the first
    // column - group - shown on the X axis.
    const groups = data.map(d => d.group);

    // Create the X-axis band scale.
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(groups)
    .range([0, this.width])
    .padding(0.2);

    // Draw the X-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
    
    // Create the Y-axis band scale.
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 14])
    .range([this.height, 0]);

    // Draw the Y-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(['#ffffcc','#4daf4a', '#e41a1c']);

    // Stack the data per subgroup.
    const stackedData = d3.stack()
    .keys(subgroups)
    (data);

    // Create a tooltip.
    const tooltip = d3.select("#stacked-bar-tooltip")
    .append("figure")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "1px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "10px")

    // Mouse function that change the tooltip when the user hovers/moves/leaves a cell.
    const mouseover = function(event, d) {
      /********** Hack! Otherwise, the following line would not work:
      const subgroupName = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key; */
      const subgroupNameObj: any = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
      const subgroupName = subgroupNameObj.key;
      /************ End of Hack! ************/
      const subgroupValue = d.data[subgroupName];
      tooltip.html("subgroup: " + subgroupName + "<br>" + "Value: " + subgroupValue)
            .style("opacity", 1)        
    }
    const mousemove = function(event, d) {
      tooltip.style("transform", "translateY(-55%)")  
            .style("left", (event.x)/2+"px")
            .style("top", (event.y)/2-30+"px")
    }
    const mouseleave = function(event, d) {
      tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
    }

    // Create and fill the stacked bars.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stackedData)
    .join("g")
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
    .selectAll("rect")    
    .data(d => d)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.data.group))
    .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
    .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("stroke", "grey")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);
  }
}
```

I created the project in SandBox (here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mclaren-8q1s4?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)) but strangely enough, it works there, but not in my Angular project...

Also, when I inspect the figure, I see that the tooltip is actually working:

[image]

What am I doing wrong or missing, that the tooltips are completely missing?

Comment: These can be difficult to position, since the figure is an svg, the tooltip div is an html element, and it can be tough to know what to select and append to. I found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153074/d3-positioning-tooltip-on-svg-element-not-working 

Without the Angular boilerplate it's tough to troubleshoot directly. You can see in this repro here that it's more than appending the tooltip to the body, bc that will make it difficult to position. https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-pond-b8m7k?file=/index.html 

Can you make a minimal Angular repro in Codesandbox?

Comment: @MGO Thanks for your reply. I created a sandbox for it. Strange, it actually works there as it should, but not in my project... Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mclaren-8q1s4?file=/src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was working all along, though due to other app components, the position was far off, so it would show at the top of the page where I would not be able to see it.

I modified the page x and y values as follows to get it to show above the mouse pointer:

```
const mousemove = function (event, d) {
      tooltip.style("transform", "translateY(-55%)")
        .style("left", (event.x - 50) + "px")
        .style("top", (event.y + 450) + "px");
}
```

My question about positioning still remains: **How do I make this part show just above the mouse pointer regardless**, **by modifying the existing code**?